# Using Interceptor with Annotation in Struts2 with Spring and Convention Plugin

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

I have been trying to use interceptor with annotation in struts2 to handle my request and responses so that I can perform some pre and post actions.

But, I have used struts 2 with convention plugin initially which I can't really change. My framework also include spring in it.

But, now problem is whenever I have been trying to use interceptor as annotation in action it gives me  following exception at the start of application.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
....
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
.....
Caused by: Unable to find interceptor class referenced by ref-name mylogging - [unknown location]
```

My code structure is quite simple:

Action class seems like:

```
@InterceptorRefs({  
    @InterceptorRef("mylogging")  
}) 
    public class LoginAction implements ModelDriven{
.....
    @Action(value="/login",results={@Result(name="success",location="/jsp/successPage.jsp"),
                @Result(name="login",location="/jsp/userLogin.jsp")})
        public String execute() {
....
```

Struts.xml:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <package  name="default"  namespace="" extends="struts-default">


     <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="mylogging" 
                class="com.lab.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor">
            </interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
    </package>
</struts>
```

My deployment descriptor body (web.xml):

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.lab.actions</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </filter>


  <filter-mapping>

    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/resources/config/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

   <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>

  </listener>
```

Now hopefully it will help to figure out why it's throwing that exception, because i don't think I need to remove implementation of **ModelDriven** from my action.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where do you declare that your action lives in the `"default"` package?

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't get you but i think  <package  name="default"  namespace="" extends="struts-default">

Comment: That defines a package, but that is not where your actions will magically appear unless you specify that's where the action belongs.

Comment: @DaveNewton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621970/what-is-the-default-package-name-for-struts-in-struts-xml tells that package name is independent of the package in which my actions exists so it's just a meaningful name that's it....

Comment: ... Interceptors are defined *inside S2 (not Java) packages*. If your action is *in another S2 (not Java) package* it knows nothing about those interceptors (unless the action's S2 (not Java) package extends the S2 (not Java) package containing the interceptors, obviously). So. What S2 (not Java) package do you believe your action to be in? Hint: it is not "default", where your interceptor is defined.

Comment: I have uploaded an image here http://postimg.org/image/yd7k1ddfp/ because I am not that much reputed to post an image as Just a new joiner. So red mark area is for interceptors and black marked area is for actions

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? I specifically differentiated between S2 packages and Java packages.

Comment: Well I think I am not getting your point S2 Packages means struts 2 packages is it something different and Java Packages is the packages where I keep my all code.. I have shared the complete directory structure...

Comment: Do you see in the struts config where you use the word "package" as an XML configuration element?

Comment: Yes obviously it's there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Convention plugin uses its own package `convention-default` which doesn't contain your package defined in struts.xml. To change that you have two options, both described in the docs [1]:

- use `@ParentPackage` annotation
- or define `<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>` in struts.xml

[1] http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-ParentPackageannotation