# We are going to migrate an application from struts 1.3 to struts 2. What is way to implement ActionForm reset method in Struts2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts, struts-1

We are going to migrate an application from Struts 1.3 to Struts 2. What is way to implement `ActionForm` reset method in Struts2.

For example In Struts 1 reset method we get values from database before action or view(JSP) is executed.

Comment: No way it's incompatible with Struts2.

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/docs/preparable-interface.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr Roman.. Is any available interceptors to done this before action.

Comment: Thanks Mr Aleksandr its working..

Comment: You can answer your question yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: @BharathkumarS Yes see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16624655/573032

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable intention is to drop `reset` methods, because they are useless.

The values could be initialized many different ways including the constructor, injection, with `@Value`, `prepare()`, resources, interceptors, etc.

To address the values populated from the db the `paramsPrepareParams` could be used. See 
[Changing parameters after bind in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13491559/573032) to learn how to get parameters before they are populated to the model objects.